# How to access a property of objects stored in list where list is stored in object in jsp using el

Tags: java, jsp

My GroupObject

```
public class GroupObject {
    private String group_name;
    private List<GroupDetails> groupMembersList;


public String getGroup_name() {
    return group_name;
}
public void setGroup_name(String group_name) {
    this.group_name = group_name;
}
public String getGroup_id() {
    return group_id;
}
public void setGroup_id(String group_id) {
    this.group_id = group_id;
}
public String getGroup_description() {
    return group_description;
}
public void setGroup_description(String group_description) {
    this.group_description = group_description;
}
public List<GroupDetails> getGroupMembersList() {
    return groupMembersList;
}
public void setGroupMembersList(List<GroupDetails> groupMembersList) {
    this.groupMembersList = groupMembersList;
}
```

GroupDetails Object stored in List above

public class GroupDetails {

```
private String member_name;
private String member_usertype;


public String getMember_name() {
    return member_name;
}

public void setMember_name(String member_fullname) {
   this.member_name = member_fullname;

}
public String getMember_usertype() {
    return member_usertype;
}
public void setMember_usertype(String member_usertype) {
    this.member_usertype = member_usertype;
}
```

}

I have servlet that populates the 'list' from the GroupObject with the GroupDetials object instances.

I am accessing the 'member_name' and 'member_usertype' property of the GroupDetails instances

Accessing in jsp below using following snippet

```
<c:forEach var="member" items="${members_list}">
                                        <li class="list-group-item title">
                                        <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/images/user.png" class="img img-circle" style="display: inline" />
                                        <strong style="display:inline;">  ${member.groupMembersList.member_name} <h5 style="display: inline;">(${member.groupMembersList.member_usertype})</h5></strong>
                                        </li> 
                                    </c:forEach>
```

I want to iterate through the groupMemberList elements and access their corressponding member_name and member_usertype but the above jsp is not working . I am unable to access the 'member_name' and 'member_usertype'.
Please help.

Comment: *I want to iterate through the groupMemberList*: so you need a forEach loop over `member.groupMembersList`. Side note: do yourself a favor, and respect the Java naming conventions. Variables and methods are camelCased. They NEVER contain underscores.

Comment: yes sir , want to iterate over groupMemberList[] and then access the groupDetail object property member_name, member_usertype. Thanks for suggesstion I'll change the naming instantly

Comment: try directly ,  ${member.member_name} As member has the GroupDetails object

Comment: You already seem to know how to use c:forEach. So use it once again to iterate over member.groupMembersList.

Comment: @Rathakrishnan Duraimoni sir the member_Name property is stored in group Details object that is in list groupMemberList stored in GroupObject . Tried wat u suggessted. gives  javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'member_name' not found on type pojo.group.GroupObject

Comment: @JB Nizet Sir could u elaborate please ...how to do what u r suggessting.

Comment: @JB Nizet sir , I tried iterating over member.groupMemberList but it gives org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/BS_AllExistingGroups.jsp(57,11) '${member.groupMemberList}' Property 'groupMemberList' not found on type pojo.group.GroupObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need, once again, a forEach loop:

```
<strong style="display:inline;">
    <c:forEach items="${member.groupMembersList}" var="groupDetails">
        ${groupDetails.member_name} ... ${groupDetails.member_usertype}
    </c:forEach>
</strong>
```

Comment: It gives org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/BS_AllExistingGroups.jsp(57,11) '${member.groupMemberList}' Property 'groupMemberList' not found on type pojo.group.GroupObject –

Comment: It gives this error because you used `groupMemberList` instead of  `groupMembersList`.

Comment: Yes exactly , silly mistake indeed. Thank you very much sir :)